# export LaTeX document

Tags: latex

Is there any java library that allows to export LaTeX document to other formats (pdf, rtf, odf, ..) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution for exporting Tex/LaTex is Tex itself. Since TeX is a full programming language, anything else would surely run into problems with more complicated documents.

There are some TeX implementations in Java, I think your best bet is [ExTex](http://www.extex.org/).

Also, some people have fun with [running TeX on a java virtual machine](http://www.monperrus.net/martin/running+tex+on+a+java+virtual+machine).